# Lagrange interpolation in JAVA

Tags: java

I have done a search around, but there isnt any code available in java hence I have write my own and I have encountered some issue. I actually got this code from a c++ source and trying hard to convert it into a workable java program.

> http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.sg/2009/12/c-c-code-lagranges-interpolation.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n;
    int i, j;
    int a;
    int x[] = null;
    int f[] = null;
    int sum = 0;
    int mult;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of point: ");
    n = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter value x for calculation: ");
    a = input.nextInt();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        System.out.println("Enter all values of x and corresponding functional vale: ");
        x = input.nextInt();
        f = input.nextInt();
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        mult = 1;
        for (j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++) {

            if (j != i) {
                mult *= (a - x[j]) / (x[i] - x[j]);

            }
            sum += mult * f[i];
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The estimated value of f(x)= " + sum);

}
```

Comment: in the source above in c++ he created an array of size x[10]
however how should i implement this in java coding

Comment: So you don't know how to make an array in java?

Comment: It's often easier to code an algorithm yourself than translating something someone else did: you wouldn't inherit his bugs.

Comment: @alex23: The algorithm is translated correctly (that 2nd, nested for loop) since that part doesn't need changes from C/C++ syntax. The problem is just basic Java syntax (and semantics). No need for `BigInteger` since Lagrange doesn't work only on integers and doesn't require the integers to be big.

Answer (score 4):

For **Lagrange Interpolation** Formula -

- You should use double data type Array
- Your should make Arrays with specific number of items

Look at the program below, you will understand.

```
    double product, sum = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the Number of Terms: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    double[] x = new double[n];
    double[] y = new double[n];

    System.out.println("Enter all the x, y terms: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        y[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.println("x = {" + Arrays.toString(x) + "}");
    System.out.println("x = {" + Arrays.toString(y) + "}");

    System.out.print("Enter a point to Find it's value: ");
    int xPoint = sc.nextInt();
    // End of inputs

    product = 1;
    // Peforming Arithmatic Operation
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                product *= (xPoint - x[j]) / (x[i] - x[j]);
            }
        }
        sum += product * y[i];

        product = 1;    // Must set to 1
    }
    System.out.println("The value at point " + xPoint + " is : " + sum);

    // End of the Program
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Langrages");
        
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no of terms: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    
    float[] ax = new float[n];
    System.out.println("Enter values of x");
    for(int i=0 ;i<n;i++) {
        ax[i] = sc.nextFloat();
    }
    
    float[] ay = new float[n];
    System.out.println("Enter values of y");
    for(int i=0 ;i<n;i++) {
        ay[i] = sc.nextFloat();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Enter the value of x\n at which you find y");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    
    float num,den;
    float term =0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        num=1;
        den=1;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
            if(j!=i) {
                num=num*(x-ax[j]);
                den = den*(ax[i]-ax[j]);    
            }
        }
        term += (num/den)*ay[i];
    }
    
    System.out.println(term);
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x[] = null;
int f[] = null;
...
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ....
    x = input.nextInt();
    f = input.nextInt();
}
```

Looks clear enough. Simply create array instance for x and f:

```
x = new int[n];
f = new int[n];
```

Somewhere after:

```
n = input.nextInt();
```

Before above `for` loop, and modify the `for` body:

```
...
x[i] = input.nextInt();
f[i] = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: He is assigning an array to an integer, he clearly means x[i] = input... etc